# Thymeleaf fragment: passing form field name as parameter

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to extract a form input as a page fragment in my Spring Boot + Thymeleaf application.

I'm doing something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>form controls</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-group" th:fragment="text-input (fieldName, fieldLabel)">
    <label th:text="${fieldLabel}">label</label>
    <input th:field="*{${fieldName}}" type="text" class="form-control"/>
    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('${fieldName}')}">
        <span th:errors="*{${fieldName}}" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I'm using the fragment this way:

```
<div th:replace="form-controls :: text-input (fieldName='firstName', fieldLabel='Name')">
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property '${fieldName}' of bean class [my.app.Dto]: Bean property '${fieldName}' is not readable or has an invalid getter method
```

So the parameter `fieldName` is not resolved correctly...

Is there something wrong in my code? Is it possible to implement something similar to my fragment in Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my issue was: Thymeleaf [**expression preprocessing**](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing).

> Preprocessing is an execution of the expressions done before the normal one that allows for modification of the expression that will eventually be executed.

So, to fix `fieldName` resolution I had to surround every `${fieldName}` exp with a double underscore:

```
<div class="form-group" th:fragment="text-input (fieldName, fieldLabel)">
    <label th:text="${fieldLabel}">label</label>
    <input th:field="*{__${fieldName}__}" type="text" class="form-control"/>
    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors(fieldName)}">
        <span th:errors="*{__${fieldName}__}" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be able to change `${#fields.hasErrors('__${fieldName}__')}` to `${#fields.hasErrors(fieldName)}` if you want.  You're right that you have to use preprocessing for the other parts.

Comment: @Metroids yes, you are right! I updated the answer. Thanks.